# React Griddle data table

Tags: reactjs, griddle

I want to hide the **filter input search field** and **settings** button. I tried below code but search field and settings button still visible.

```
<Griddle 
              plugins={[plugins.LocalPlugin]}
              data={griddleData}
              showFilter={false}
              showSettings={false}
              resultsPerPage={10}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since what you tried is not working, I assume you are using Griddle v1.  The syntax you were using is the old v0 syntax which is now obsolete:

> ```
>           showFilter={false}
>           showSettings={false}
> ```

In Griddle v1, you can create your own layout component by defining the following:

```
const griddleLayout = ({Table, Pagination, Filter, SettingsWrapper}) => (
    <div>
        <Pagination/>
        <Table/>
    </div>
);
```

Above you can notice that I decided to only display Pagination and Table, hence hiding the Filter and SettingsWrapper.

And then you are able to override the default layout component so it uses your own:

```
<Griddle
    ...
    components={{
        Layout: griddleLayout
    }}
    ...
</Griddle>
```

Refs:

- Old syntax (v0): https://griddlegriddle.github.io/v0-docs/customization.html
- New syntax (v1): https://griddlegriddle.github.io/Griddle/docs/customization/

Comment: please provide an explanation in addition to your code snippet

Comment: @julian-soro Done. I think it will be enough now.